# Jenkins Pipeline: Try/catch inside a retry block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, try-catch, jenkins-pipeline

I have problems with my Jenkins pipeline. I want to do the following: 
if the Build Environment already exists in the Workspace then execute a (incremental) build using the previous Environment.

If that fails retry again with a clean build (delete previous Build Environment, then build again)

I am trying to do this by:

```
retry(1) {
        try {
            prepareEnvironment()
            setupBuildEnvironment() // sets up environment if it is not present yet
            runBuild()
        } catch (e) {
            echo 'Err: Incremental Build failed with Error: ' + e.toString()
            echo '     Trying to build with a clean Workspace'
            removeOldBuildEnvironment()
        } finally {
            cleanupEnvironment()
        }
    }
```

When I run this in Jenkins and the `runBuild()` step fails I get:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.Exception java.lang.String

I think the problem is the try/catch inside the retry(1) block. Any suggestions how to fix that

I also tried it without the retry. Here I had the problem that if the

```
bat "..."
```

step inside runBuild() returns a exception the pipeline Stage is marked as fail even if I catch the exception and the clean build is a success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

The error message is not because the `try/catch` but because of throwing exception in the `prepareEnvironment`, `setupBuildEnvironment` or `runBuild` methods, like `throw new Exception("message")` which is not allowed in sandbox mode. What is allowed is using the `error` step like so:

```
def runBuild() {
    // ...
    error "ERR"
}
```

This step will throw a `hudson.AbortException` with the message specified.

The catch block in you code will catch this exception and print the proper message then invoke `removeOldBuildEnvironment`

On the other hand with this modification done your script will still not work as expected as the exception is swallowed by the catch block, so the retry step will not execute the code again. To make it work the exception needs to be thrown again from the catch block (note that you have to use `retry(2)` instead of `retry(1)`)

```
retry(2) {
    try {
        prepareEnvironment()
        setupBuildEnvironment() // sets up environment if it is not present yet
        runBuild()
    } catch (e) {
        echo 'Err: Incremental Build failed with Error: ' + e.toString()
        echo '     Trying to build with a clean Workspace'
        removeOldBuildEnvironment()
        throw e
    } finally {
        cleanupEnvironment()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to script approval (in Manage Jenkins, somewhere at the bottom) and approve `toString` method for Exception.

If you can't find script approval, then install plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin first.

You might need to visit that page when you see `RejectedAccessException`.

Answer (score -6):

Try to uncheck the checkbox "Use Groovy Sandbox".

Comment: Be aware that this allows the pipeline script full access to your complete Jenkins instance (basically shell access to the master and all nodes)